# How to get domain name from PL/SQL in Apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an apex application hosted at a certain address which not very user friendly. Let's say : **aaze_a442.com**

I have another domain (which is user friendly) that redirects to the **aaze_a442.com** let's say : **niceexample.com** such that APEX application will be transparently accessed from **niceexample.com**

The redirection works nicely.

I'm trying to get the nice domain name from PL/SQL. As a result I'm expecting to get : **niceexample.com**

I'm using the following query :

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM dual;
```

But it doesn't return **niceexample.com**, it returns instead **aaze_a442**

Does anyone know how to get the domain instead of the host name please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the Answer :

```
OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env ('REQUEST_PROTOCOL') || '://' || OWA_UTIL.get_cgi_env ('HTTP_HOST')
```

returns : https://niceexample.com